# Display Colorbox Onload Page Load

Tags: cookies, colorbox, onload

I'm working on code that will a message for first time visitors using ColorBox. I've been bootstrapping code, and this is what I have so far...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script>


function loadMsg()
{
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($.cookie('newsletter') != '0') {
$.colorbox({href:"newsletter.html"});
$.cookie('newsletter', '1', { expires: 60}); }
}}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadMsg()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Will this keep the pop-up from showing up a second time. Can you help me figure out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What plugin are you using for cookies?  I doubt that $.cookie('newsletter') returns the string value '0' when no cookie exists. I imagine it returns a falsey value. Are you sure it shouldn't be something like this:

```
if (!$.cookie('newsletter')) {
    $.colorbox({href:"newsletter.html"});
    $.cookie('newsletter', '1', { expires: 60}); }
}
```

Or drop the cookie plugin and write your own cookie detecting code.  It isn't difficult for a one-off use case such as this.

Answer (score 0):

The code above may be spitting *is not a function* and *is undefined* errors.

Here's the **updated code** that should work today (notice that I'm using the [jQuery Cookie library](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadMsg(){

        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            if (!jQuery.cookie('popupcookie')) {
                jQuery.colorbox({href:"newsletter.html", width: 640, height: 460});
                jQuery.cookie('popupcookie', '1', { expires: 1}); }
        })}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadMsg()">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

This should get you going. The expiration time is set to 1 day in this example btw.